# rxjs and the bad practice of if-then-else which i am trying to avoid

Tags: rxjs

I have an rxjs observable and i am planning to print only one color train.
The code can be tried out at 
https://codesandbox.io

```
import { from } from "rxjs";
import { merge, filter ,tap,} from "rxjs/operators";

const nextTrain$ = from(['Yellow', 'Neon', 'Amber']);

const yellowTrain$ = 
nextTrain$
  .pipe(
   filter(color => color === 'Yellow'),
   tap(console.log(`Yellow Color Train is comming`))
   )

const greenTrain$ = nextTrain$
  .pipe(
   filter((color) => color === 'Green'),
   tap(console.log(`Green Color Train is comming`))
   )

const blueTrain$ = nextTrain$
  .pipe(
   filter((color) => color === 'Blue'),
   tap(console.log(`Blue Color Train is comming`))
   )

merge(yellowTrain$,
  greenTrain$,
  blueTrain$).subscribe()
```

I was expecting only the statement 
Yellow Color Train is comming 
to be printed but i get all the three statements printed any ideas what i am doing wrong here ?

Also in the code box attaching subscribe to the merge statement is erroring out any ideas what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `tap` is being used incorrectly, you should pass functions, like this:

```js
tap(() => console.log(`Yellow Color Train is comming`))
```

The way you wrote it was incorrect since you were always calling `console.log` (thus all the messages in console), but calls to `console.log` do not return functions (they return `undefined`) since `tap` expects one, so `tap` essentially wasn't working at all.

> Also in the code box attaching subscribe to the merge statement is erroring out any ideas what am i doing wrong ?

You're doing the wrong imports. Here's the right one:

```js
import { from, merge } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

[Here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#import-paths)'s the explanation about how to do the right imports.

Final:

```js
import { from, merge } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const nextTrain$ = from(['Yellow', 'Neon', 'Amber']);

const yellowTrain$ =
  nextTrain$
    .pipe(
      filter(color => color === 'Yellow'),
      tap(() => console.log(`Yellow Color Train is comming`))
    )

const greenTrain$ = nextTrain$
  .pipe(
    filter((color) => color === 'Green'),
    tap(() => console.log(`Green Color Train is comming`))
  )

const blueTrain$ = nextTrain$
  .pipe(
    filter((color) => color === 'Blue'),
    tap(() => console.log(`Blue Color Train is comming`))
  )

merge(yellowTrain$,
  greenTrain$,
  blueTrain$).subscribe();
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for providing not only the code but also the explanation it's immensely useful for Junior developers